# reactJS How can I add a search filter for data from the db

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a search input to filter the data I receive from the database.
Could anybody walk me through how I can go about filtering and displaying on the results that are searched. I want to search for the MeetingName that was mapped from items. Right now the app is displaying the entire list of items from the database.

Thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getItems, deleteItem } from "../actions/itemActions";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Directory extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getItems();
    }

    onDeleteClick = (id) => {
        this.props.deleteItem(id);
    }

    render() {
        const { items } = this.props.item;

        return(
            <div>
                <Input type="text" placeholder="search"/>
                <br/>
                <Table>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Day</th><th>Time</th><th>Meeting Name</th><th>Address</th><th>City</th><th>Zip Code</th><th></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    {items.map(({ _id, Day, Time, MeetingName, Address, City, Zip }) => (
                        <tbody key={_id}>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{Day}</td><td>{Time}</td><td>{MeetingName}</td><td>{Address}</td><td>{City}</td><td>{Zip}</td>
                            {/*<Button
                                className="remove-btn"
                                color="danger"
                                size="sm"
                                onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, _id)}
                            >
                                &times;
                            </Button>*/}
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    ))}
                    </Table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Directory.propTypes = {
    getItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    item: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    item: state.item
})


export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { getItems, deleteItem }
    )(Directory);
```

Comment: You can use [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid) like library which provide easily handling of search feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change few things in your component

1. Initialise state in constructor as below

   ```
   this.state = { searchedValue: '' };
   ```
2. Add an onChange event listener on `input`

   ```
   <input type="text" placeholder="search" onChange={this.onSearch} value={this.state.searchedValue} />
   ```
3. Change the state with typed value when `onSearch` function is called

   ```
   onSearch = (event) => {
       this.setState({ searchedValue: event.target.value });
   }
   ```
4. Filter the `items` list with the searchedValue in `render` function

   ```
   const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => item.meetingName.includes(this.state.searchedValue));
   ```
5. Use the `filteredItems` array to create multiple `tr`

As stated in the comment on your post, [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid) is a nice option but you can choose what fits best for your application